# trying to use usercontrols from different project in same solution?

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I am trying to use usercontrols from a different project in my asp.net 3.5 solution?

how can I use them? what is the reference?

Comment: google "asp.net reuseing user control"

Comment: Google returns a link to this page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, user controls are designed to be use within a single project. This is because user control has two parts - the markup (ascx) file and code-behind. If you compile the project into a library the the code-behind class gets packaged in the dll but not the ascx part. The mark-up (ascx) contains the actual control tree and hence w/o it user control cannot be used. So one of the solution to share user controls is to compile user control's code into a library and copy ascx files into the target project.

But the better solution is to package user control's markup (ascx) as embedded resource of library project and then use a custom virtual path provider to load it from the resource. See [this code-project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/user-controls/EmbeddedUserControl.aspx) that describes this technique.

Comment: is there no easier solution? :(

Comment: @user603007, the easiest solution is to copy user control files (code and markup) into new project which is not-maintainable. More maintainable approach is to package code and then share markup by direct copy or shared folder (or shared folder in source control system such as VSS). However, the best approach is to package both code and markup together!

Answer (score 0):

one way I do this is to have a 
 1. web app project with shared usercontrols, 
 2. which then referenced by other web app projects that need to use the controls 
 3. for each app/website that uses controls create a virt directory pointing to ascx location so they can be included in your pages

there are variations of this when deployed to production of course.. depending on your deployment preferences. 
Yes, I agree that generally if you want to re-use, then server controls / class lib should be used but it's often easier and faster to implement complex UI in usercontrols and share as above. 
Also works when reusing usercontrols from a different existing web app.. just create a virt dir pointing to ascx location and reference the app dll (or just drop in your BIN)

Comment: ah ok.. VinayC described pretty much the same but 13 min earlier ))